# How to force cygwin to run windows python executeable and not the one in its own bin directory

Tags: python, cygwin

When I execute keyword python in cygwin, it runs the python that exists inside its own internal directory. I cannot remove this python since it is required for some other packages that were downloaded into cygwin and was thus installed automatically.

Please see this:
eeng ~

```
$ where python
C:\cygwin64\bin\python
C:\Users\eeng1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\eeng1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

eeng ~
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I want that cygwin uses the second directory for Python executeable rather than the first one. What do I do now? Please note that the /usr/bin/python is not found in windows $PATH. So this problem cannot be fixed from that way.

Comment: I don't see this; my cygwin finds the Windows python.

Comment: what is the result given by the commands "where python" and "which python" on your machine?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\python39\python.exe`, and then two python executables buried in my AppData. Cygwin's `bin` folders don't show up at all. `which` gives me the one in Program Files.

Comment: ok the problem on my end is that when I downloaded some packages into cygwin using its setup, it downloaded some versions of python automatically with it. Now I cannot uninstall them since those other packages will not work otherwise. I am kind of stuck.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` inside cygwin say? Might the trick be to add `$(cygpath 'C:\Program Files\python39\')`to the left end of PATH? NOTE: cygwin and windows uses differing line endings in text files - which might become a problem if you're using an *.EXE instead of the cygwin executable on cygwin-based python scripts.

Comment: The $PATH as seen from inside Cygwin by executing your command shows this at the start "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:". This is certainly the culprit. Also, the only entry containing the word python and is between two colons is "/cygdrive/c/Ruby30-x64/bl/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts". This does not seem right does it?

Comment: Any reason to ask in multiple place ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711956/how-to-force-cygwin-to-run-specific-application-when-multiple-with-same-name-exi

Comment: I have not yet found a solution that works for me and I want to fix this as a priority and know no one that can help me

Comment: It appears you have a mess with multiple executables; not easy to tidy up. Sorry, can't help with that.

Comment: I provided 3 solutions, and none is good for you ? May be you should not use the Windows version of Python from Cygwin and use it from CMD

Comment: Since windows has WSL built in.. why are people even messing with Cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

I added this line into the .bashrc:

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/:$PATH
```

Now running `which python` does not give the python stored inside the cygwin `/usr/bin/` but gives the one one in the windows path.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Either provide the absolute PATH to your cygwin (you could write a cover script which just calles Windows python, so you don't have to type the full path every time), or change your PATH variable that your Windows Python directory comes earlier than /usr/bin.

For instance, if you create a shell script named `winpython` with the content

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
C:/Users/eeng1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39 "$@"
```

you can use `winpython` instead of `python` to get the Windows version.